# useRef div element not auto-focusing on page load despite focusing in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently attempting to add some keyboard events to my app, which trigger if certain codes are pressed.

This is done inside of my DashboardWrapper component, which is essentially just a styling component, but renders any children inside of it:

```
<div className="full-vh full-vw flex-center" ref={wrapper} onKeyDown={handleKeyboardEvents}>
  {children}
</div>
```

This component is rendered like this inside of a parent page:

```
<DashboardWrapper>
  { children in here} 
</DashboardWrapper>
```

The component uses the useRef hook, and assigns it to a wrapper variable, like so:

```
const wrapper = useRef(null)
```

Then, inside of a useEffect, I assign an event listener to it, calling a function which triggers some console logs:

```
useEffect(() => {

        wrapper.current.focus()

        if (wrapper.current !== null) {
            console.log("Running inside of if..");
            wrapper.current.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyboardEvents)
        }

        return wrapper.current.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyboardEvents)
    }, [])
```

It also calls 'focus()', which should auto-focus the div in question upon page load - but for whatever reason, it isn't working.

For reference, this is my handleKeyboardEvents function:

```
const handleKeyboardEvents = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {

        console.log(e.code);
        console.log(e);

        if (e.ctrlKey && e.code === "KeyS") {
            console.log("control and s pressed");
        }
    }
```

The only way I can get the keyboard events to start firing is to manually tab between the different elements, until I reach the div in question. Then it works.

What I'm trying to achieve here, in short, is to be able to trigger the keyboard events at any time, except when an element (such as an input) is in focus.

There may be a more efficient way to do this - but this is my stab at it for now.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding `tabIndex="-1"` to the `<div>` element so that it can be focused.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I don’t think this will allow the div to always be focused when other elements aren’t focused though right?

Comment: No. This should answer your original question of having the element be focused on page load.